# MongoDB range query between two values - Repeating the field vs. two operators on the same field

Tags: mongodb, performance, syntax

I just had a question about the MongoDB querying language. I have a datastore containing a lot of geo-spatial and time series data and I'm attempting to query for records within a time range.

If I'm attempting to search for records who have a field between two values I'm obviously using the $gte and $lte operators.

Consider the two below queries:

Query #1 - Specifying the field twice

```
{"RecivedTime": {$gte: 1000000}, "ReceivedTime": {$lte: 2000000}}
```

Query #2 - Two operators on the same field

```
{"ReceivedTime": {$gte: 1000000, $lte: 2000000}}
```

I just wondered if these two were, ultimately the same query/question that the server will process. Or if the server will process these two queries differently?

I'd expect that *ultimately* the queries should be identical, but perhaps it's just a coincidence (placebo) but I'm sure Query #1 runs slower on my database server. Excuse my mad ramblings but, I wondered if it was possible that the first might not use the index in the same way, and instead try to process the two filters individually and then find the "union" of the two result sets?

If the latter is true and they do perform differently, which would be the most efficient to use?

Comment: Is "Query #1" accepted by your server?  On mongoplayground.net there is an error: `Invalid query: Line 5: Duplicate key`.

Comment: You can also look at the `"winningPlan"` of `db.collection.find({"ReceivedTime": {"$gte": 1000000, "$lte": 2000000}}).explain()` to see the actual query selected to run.

Comment: Hi there @rickhg12hs. Thanks so much for your inputs! Yes query#1 is definitely accepted by Mongo Server at least through MongoDBCompass. Perhaps the issue lies there. That's an amazing suggestion though, I never realised the explain functionality, I'll try that out and post any results I find!